# How to declare a macro with a variable argument list?

Tags: macros, tufte, xparse

I am looking for a macro with two optional arguments and tried the following code:

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}
%
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[demo]{graphics}
\usepackage{easyfig}
%
%% Usage \mfig[position][trim]{name-figure}{caption}{label}
%
\NewDocumentCommand{\mfig}{o o m m m}{%
    \begin{marginfigure}[\IfValueTF{#1}{#1}{0}cm]
        \Figure[trim={.0\width} {\IfValueTF{#2}{#2}{.05}\height}%
            {.0\width} {.0\height},clip,%
            width=\linewidth,keepaspectratio=true,%
            caption={#4},label={#5},center,here]{#3}
    \end{marginfigure}%
}
%
\begin{document}

\section{A simple test}

\lipsum[1]
\mfig{myfigure}{This is just a caption to the demo figure.}{fig:test}
Figure~\ref{fig:test} shows a test. \lipsum[3].
\end{document}
```

The first optional argument gives the margin figure vertical position and the second gives the trim coordinates (an inferior cut-off actually).

It is ok to to use:

```
\mfig[-1.5]{name}{caption}{label}
```

to move vertically the margin figure about 1.5cm up, for instance, and with the default trim coordinates of .05, but I am unable to use

```
\mfig[.55]{name}{caption}{label}
```

to cut-off 55% of my graphic, while using the default position of 0cm, because my "macro" is unable to recognize the optional argument #2 without to explicitly use the #1.

So, my question is: is there any way to specify only the #2 optional argument while the macro accepts the default #1 argument like the above?

Comment: optional arguments are positional so you can place one in a different position such as `o m o m m` but it's usually better to consider a variant syntax such as [a,b] or `[a=x, b=y]` that is the key value syntax of `\includegraphics`  is designed to allow optional arguments without this problem, but your wrapper hides that.

Comment: @David Yes, I can see it now ... much more clever, and simple, I believe. But I did not understood your variant syntax note. How does it changes my macro/function declaration and usage?

Comment: if you have two optional arguments and put one before and one after the mandatory argument they can be distinguished. with `o o m` if you have just one `[]` argument it has to be `#1` but if you have `o m o` you can have `\foo[a]{b}[c]` and distinguish `\foo[a]{b}` from `\foo{b}[c]`

Comment: But how to use [a,b] variant?

Comment: in this case probably not (although you could distinguish by type) but having named keys makes it easier to implement and easier to use. It was more a general comment that having a comma separated list is better than lots of optional arguments cg `\documentclass[12pt,oneside,german,fleqn]{article}` where the options can be omitted or not and in any order

Comment: As a note, I would very much recommend using the default-value syntax for optional arguments in the argspec. Instead of `oommm`, use `O{0cm} O{0.05} mmm`.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use keys?  That way you can have practically as many *parameters* as you would like.

Of the many ways you could do this, here's one:

In the preface you could have

```
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\def\mycaption{default caption}
\def\mylabel{default label}
\def\myfigwidth{0pt}
\def\myfigheight{0.05}
\pgfkeys{/jotagah/myfig/.cd,
  caption/.store in=\mycaption,
  label/.store in=\mylabel,
  fig width/.store in=\myfigwidth,
  fig height/.store in=\myfigheight,
  }
```

Then you could define your function as

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\mfig}{om}{%
    \pgfkeys{/jotagah/myfig/.cd,
      fig width=0cm,
      fig height=0.05,
      #1}%%
    \begin{marginfigure}[\myfigwidth]
        \Figure[trim={.0\width} {\myfgheight\height}%
            {.0\width} {.0\height},clip,%
            width=\linewidth,keepaspectratio=true,%
            caption=\mycaption,label=\mylabel,center,here]{#2}
    \end{marginfigure}%
```

Comment: @Ellett I do not know the pgfkeys package and so I have to read a bit more to understand your solution. May I ask you how to call my macro/function using only #1, only #2,both, or none of the optional arguments?